# How do I identify "infinitive clauses/phrases" and "subjects"?

Tags: infinitives, parts-of-speech, relative-clauses

In sentences such as the following, there is (as I understand it) an infinitive clause and an infinitive phrase. Which part is the infinitive clause and which part is the infinitive phrase? And what is the subject?

Examples:

> One thing to do about this is to stop feeding animals junk food.
>
> One way to improve your dancing skills is to practice on a hot tin roof.

Comment: Both sentences contain subjectless infinitive clauses. The first clause in each is a relative infinitive clause (modifying _thing_ and _way_), and the second clause in each is a noun complement clause. Neither one is a phrase; they're all clauses. And they are all missing a subject. But the subject is reconstructible, as usual. All of the subjects are indefinite (though the second one uses _you_ and may in fact refer to the addressee instead of a generic person).

Comment: However the subject of the *sentence* is **thing**.

Comment: No, _thing_ is the head noun of the subject NP, but the subject of the sentence is in fact the whole NP _One thing to do about this_. Calling _thing_ the "subject" just confuses the issue when it's also the object of _do_ in the infinitive clause.

Comment: thank you. i understand the subject aspect of this. i'm still a bit confused about the clause/phrase bit. your explanation makes sense and seems informed, but this reference confuses me:
[link] (http://www2.cambridge.org/interchangearcade/launch.do?activityID=560&level=3&unit=7&type=Cup_matching&stage=1)
it uses sentences like those i gave above but refers to them as containing "Infinitive clauses and phrases."

Comment: Also, what is the exact function of the infinitives in these sentences? With "One thing to do..." to do seems to me like an adjective modifying one thing. The latter seems like it could be a noun, especially since a gerund could be used in place of it. But if it's a relative clause, I guess must be an adjective also...answering the question, 'which one?' Is this right?
Thanks.

Comment: It seems some online grammars use infinitive phrase or infinitive clause for the same thing, an infinitive ( either standing alone or having an object or adverbial part). In my view unnecessary terms as no one has problems recognizing an infinitive or an an infinitve having sentence parts as an object or an adverbial.

Comment: @JohnLawler Are clauses not phrases?

Comment: @Araucaria: No. Clauses represent propositions and have subject and predicate, in English at least. Phrases are other constituents, including individual words (_I_ is a noun phrase for instance).  Infinitives and gerunds are always clauses in what generative grammarians call "underlying structure", but a number of rules conspire to move or remove their subjects in "surface structure", so all that's left is a verb phrase.

Comment: @JohnLawler Yes, I get that not all phrases are clauses, but surely clauses are phrases, especially when they're constituents?

Comment: @JohnLawler For example, when you have a finite clause functioning as subject of a sentence, surely that's a phrase?

Comment: @Araucaria: In grammatical practice, _clause_ and _phrase_  are disjoint.  What _phrase_ means is 'non-clausal constituent'. What other meaning do you think it has? I think you're being confused by tree structure; a finite clause as the subject is a noun phrase which consists of a clause [s [np [s `S` s] np] [vp...vp] s]

Comment: @JohnLawler Well don't you call clauses functioning as subject noun **phrases**?

Comment: @JohnLawler I would just have thought a phrase is any kind of constituent, and a clause is a special kind of phrase. (shrugs)

Comment: ... but the np only exists in the upper clause; what it has underneath is irrelevant to that clause; and the np upstairs has nothing to do with the clause downstairs. This is the heart of the cyclic principle, which allows each clause to apply rules independently. Since they derive from bottom to top, each clause is considered independently, and may be chewed up or deleted by the next cycle. So whether you call it a phrase or a clause depends on which cycle you're referring to. Just like whether you call something a tensor or a vector depends on what you're referring to.

Comment: @JohnLawler So why not just let a clause be a special kind of phrase with it's own internal structure? It's a bit of a bind saying that it's a clause downstairs but not upstairs when alternatively  if clauses are just a special type of phrase you can just differentiate between it's internal structure and its syntactic function - it seems to me anyhow ...

Comment: That's an alternative way of handling it; but what I described is the way that's evolved in practice. It keeps the focus on the individual cycle. McCawley is pretty good on the cyclic principle, by the way. It's a really productive part of grammatical theory.

Comment: @JohnLawler I'm putting off reading the McCawley, though I don't know how long I can do it  for. Maybe I should start soonish.

Comment: The [introduction and quite a lot of other stuff](https://books.google.com/books?id=k6-C5AWWqjQC&pg=PR4#v=twopage&q&f=false) is on the Web. Trying to figure out why you want a special term "phrase", I wonder what it would denote that "constituent" doesn't already denote. Phrases and clauses are both constituents; how can you justify introducing a term "phrase" with the same meaning and truth set as "constituent?

Comment: @JohnLawler Because "constituent" tends to refer to a clause level phrase, secondly because "constituent" seems to pertain more to  external grammatical relations considerations than what type of chunk a word is internally. Lastly because "phrase" might be ok for "constituent" but "constituent" isn't ok for "phrase".

Comment: @JohnLawler So "this is a noun constituent" falls flat on its face ...

Comment: _Constituent_ refers to clause- and phrase-level items, as well as individual words. What it excludes is strings that  are not complete constituents, or that consist of parts of more than one constituent. It's important because it turns out that syntactic processes only apply to constituents. "Phrase" is indeed the normal combining form -- NP, VP, PP, etc. But not SP.

Answer (score 2):

There is no clause in the sentences. The first infinitives in both sentences are adjectival which cannot be separated from the noun phrases which begin the two sentences to form the subjects of *to be* verbs *is* and *is* respectively. The second elements after *to be* verbs are infinitive phrases which perform the functions as the complements to the subjects. There is no clause among the infinitives because there is no finite verb in them all.

From Idoko, Ejike Celestine (Celestial Academic Centre)

Answer (score 1):

Modern grammarians consider such constructions clauses, not phrases.  What traditional grammarians called infinitive phrases are now called infinitival clauses, a type of nonfinite clause.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to do about this is to stop feeding animals junk food.
Subject, placed at the end: to stop to feed animals junk food
- to stop something: to-infinitive + object
- object replaced by: infinitive phrase
Verb, linking verb: is
be-complement: one thing to do about this
to do about this: a sub-element of: a thing

to practise on a hot tin roof: subject, placed at the end

is: linking verb

one way to improve your dancing skills: be complement

to improve your dancing skills: infinitive phrase, sub-element of: one way

Answer (score 0):

Modern is as Modern does, so forever shall confusion reign!

A phrase used to be a phrase, a clause used to be a clause, and a sentence used to be a complete thought. Those days are long gone! There are now so many re-interpretations of so many supposedly 'pointless and useless' grammar rules that everything that used to be known is known no longer.  I can not see any progress in how students are taught English compared to how it used to be taught many decades ago.

English Grammar should never have become interpretative.  It should be learned and used to interpret the meaning of sentences, and those sentences should be complete thoughts; else, what's the point?

Grammar should be learned from older books, and newer books should be used to create lists of newfangled terms simply so that you can pass a test.  There are too many confused students. What do modern grammerians have to say about that?  Good Luck.  I suggest that you go to google books online and download free ebooks by Reed & Kellogg. They are clear and concise.  Believe me, there's nothing new in grammar, just new opinions that confuse the people.